# How does Android know a method is deprecated?

Tags: java, android, deprecated

I am trying to call one of Glide's overloaded methods and it seems this method is deprecated. E.g. Android shows a warning for passing a URL object:

`Glide.with(mContext).`<strike>`load`</strike>`(url);`

How does Android system know a method of a library is deprecated? Do the library author specify which Android versions are supported? We usually set our minimum SDK, not the maximum SDK, so the author probably has no control over when their method is deprecated. Any ideas?

Comment: If I release a library today (v 1.0.0) later on I can decide to deprecate some problematic code in my next release (v 1.0.1) by using the annotation @Deprecated, that only means if I use an older version of the library the deprecation is bypassed but that is a bad practice.

Comment: Author has complete control over the depreciation annotations of methods

Answer (score 1):

A method is shown as deprecated when it has `@Deprecated` annotation on the declaration. Ex:

```
@Deprecated
void setTitle(String title);
```

You can set require API version for a method via annotation `@RequiresApi(API_TARGET_LEVEL)`. Ex:

```
@RequiresApi(22)
void setTitle(String title);
```

A method is marked as deprecated can be removed in the future

Comment: So, by using `@Deprecated` we basically warn our library users to prepare for removal of the deprecated element in near future, right?

Comment: Yes. And something (ex: `Camera`) on android is marked Deprecated 2 or 3 year ago, but it also exist now.

Answer (score 1):

To use external library, for example `Glide`, in your `Gradle` file, you probably specify something like:

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
   annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.5.0'
}
```

The version of `Glide` is specified. So that particular `version of library` is included in your app.

In the library's source code, the annotation `@Deprecated` is added in front of function which is deprecated, something like:

```
@Deprecated
public void someDeprecatedFunction() {
```

Hence IDE shows it as `deprecated` with special formatting / highlighting.